# MySql storedprocedure not executing frm asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am able to execute MySQL sp. In server it works fine, but when called from asp.net it is not working properly. Below is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCategoryForBackLinkID`(IN BLID int, OUT CatID int)
BEGIN
        SELECT CategoryID INTO CatID FROM backlink where BackLinkID = BLID;
END
```

Below is the asp.net code

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("GetCategoryForBackLinkID");
MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection();

//ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["linkbuilding1Entities3"];
con1.ConnectionString = "server=67.227.183.117;User Id=rammu1;Pwd=eframmu1;database=linkbuilding1;Persist Security Info=True";
cmd1.Connection = con1;
using (cmd1.Connection)
{
     cmd1.Connection.Open();

     MySqlParameter returnParameter1 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("BLID", MySqlDbType.Int16);
     returnParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
     returnParameter1.Value = maximumbacklinid;

     MySqlParameter returnParameter2 = cmd1.Parameters.Add("CatID", MySqlDbType.Int16);
     returnParameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

     cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
     CategID = (Int16)returnParameter2.Value;
```

The error I get is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GetCategoryForBackLinkID' at line 1.

What is possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, I'm not 100% sure but looks like you need to assing your [`CommandType`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtype) property like;

```
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Since you using store procedure, this property is `Text` by default. That's why your program thinks your `"GetCategoryForBackLinkID"` string is a valid SQL query, not a store procedure.

> When you set the CommandType property to StoredProcedure, you should
>   set the CommandText property to the name of the stored procedure. The
>   command executes this stored procedure when you call one of the
>   Execute methods.

```
using(MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(connString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   // Add your parameter values.
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
   CategID = (int)returnParameter2.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IN Your connection string one keyword is wrong write Data source not database there.

```
"server=67.227.183.117;User Id=rammu1;Pwd=eframmu1;Data Source=linkbuilding1;Persist Security Info=True";
```